# Can't directly paste a string directly in a cell of Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

in the Jupyter notebook version 7 or latest, I can't directly paste a string/text etc directly in the cell but first have to do a work around (paste it in the search bar and then recopy and then paste in the cell ), in contrast to it if I use an older version i.e., **6.5.2**, It works like it is supposed to do.
Is it a problem in the new notebook of If I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be browser related problem:

1. Update browser
2. Try right click with Shift held down anywhere in JupyterLab, using any browser, to open your browser's standard right click menu. from there you can try copy paste.
3. Ensure that your browser allows clipboard access for Jupyter Notebook. Some browsers may have restrictions on clipboard access due to security considerations.
4. Try to run Jupyter Notebook in various environments if so then you need to reinstall Jupyter Notebook.